# Uploading file to server with android

Tags: php, android, apache

I have been working on an app on android that should grab an image from the sd card and then upload it to my server. I was able to get the pic to upload to a server using this as the uri the example gave "http://www.androidexample.com/media/UploadToServer.php. However the image will not upload to my localhost server i am using the local host from a wifi from an android device using URI 192.1xx.x.xxx/uploadtoserver.php. I recieve a serverresponse 200 and OK.

I have googled for answers and researched for 3 days and cannot get this to work.

My Code:

Java part:

```
public class UploadToServer extends Activity {

TextView messageText;
Button uploadButton;
int serverResponseCode = 0;
ProgressDialog dialog = null;

String upLoadServerUri = null;

/**********  File Path *************/
String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();

final String uploadFilePath = path + "/MyApp/Temp/";
final String uploadFileName = "temp.png";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_to_server);

    uploadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
    messageText  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageText);

    messageText.setText("Uploading file path :- '/mnt/sdcard/"+uploadFileName+"'");

    /************* Php script path ****************/
    upLoadServerUri = "http://192.168.1.144/UploadToServer.php";

    uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(UploadToServer.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
                                }
                            });                      

                         uploadFile(uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);

                    }
                  }).start();        
            }
        });
}

public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {


      String fileName = sourceFileUri;

      HttpURLConnection conn = null;
      DataOutputStream dos = null;  
      String lineEnd = "\r\n";
      String twoHyphens = "--";
      String boundary = "*****";
      int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
      byte[] buffer;
      int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
      File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

      if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

           dialog.dismiss(); 

           Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"
                               +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);

           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                   messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"
                           +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
               }
           }); 

           return 0;

      }
      else
      {
           try { 

                 // open a URL connection to the Servlet
               FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
               URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

               // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
               conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
               conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
               conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
               conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
               conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
               conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
               conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

               dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
               dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                                         + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

               // create a buffer of  maximum size
               bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

               bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
               buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

               // read file and write it into form...
               bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

               while (bytesRead > 0) {

                 dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                 bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                 bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                 bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                }

               // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

               // Responses from the server (code and message)
               serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
               String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

               Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                       + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

               if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                          +" http://192.168.1.144/UploadToServer.php/"
                                          +uploadFileName;

                            messageText.setText(msg);
                            Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "File Upload Complete.", 
                                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });                
               }    

               //close the streams //
               fileInputStream.close();
               dos.flush();
               dos.close();

          } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

              dialog.dismiss();  
              ex.printStackTrace();

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                      Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "MalformedURLException", 
                                                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });

              Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
          } catch (Exception e) {

              dialog.dismiss();  
              e.printStackTrace();

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                      Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", 
                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });
              Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "
                                               + e.getMessage(), e);  
          }
          dialog.dismiss();       
          return serverResponseCode; 

       } // End else block 
     }
```

}

Since it works on one server i believe this is a server-side issue

PHP part

```
<?php
 $target_path1 = "var/www/images/"
 $target_path1 = $target_path1 . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $target_path1)) {
echo "Success";
} else{
 echo "fail";}
 ?>
```

Comment: did u resolved this error and got the output?

Answer (score 2):

```
 <?php
    $target_path1 = "/var/www/images/"
    $target_path1 = $target_path1 . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $target_path1)) { 
        echo "Success";
    } else {
        echo "fail";
    }
 ?>
```

It looks like you were referencing a relative directory: `var/www/images/` which, if your php file was in `/var/www/` to begin with would be pointing to `/var/www/var/www/images/` which I doubt is what you were intending.

Just change `$target_path1` to make it an absolute path `/var/www/images/`

Comment: Here in my case it is showing "Started Uploading" but after that no failure or success message

Comment: It displays the message of "Started uploading" but after long time also nothing happens, i checked my network connection it is good and my file size is also small only.