# Android photo or gallery path not a file

Tags: android

I'm attempting to use the upload to server tutorials you see everywhere. Like [Uploading file to server with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17057029/uploading-file-to-server-with-android) and they all use the same function with the same start and here's mine:

```
    String fileName = sourceFileUri;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;  
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 

    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {              
         Log.i(Utils.TAG, "uploadFile: Source File not exist: " + sourceFileUri );
         return 0;

    }
```

Problem is, it's not recognizing any of my image I either take or select from the gallery.

Gallery:
`uploadFile: Source File not exist :content://media/external/images/media/342`
Photo: `uploadFile: Source File not exist: file:///storage/emulated/0/MyDir/blah`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With respect to `content://media/external/images/media/342`, that's a `Uri` for a `ContentProvider`. Since you do not need a file to upload to a server, just the file's contents, get an `InputStream` on the `Uri` from [a `ContentResolver` using `openInputStream()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openInputStream%28android.net.Uri%29).

With respect to `file:///storage/emulated/0/MyDir/blah`, while that `Uri` points to a file, the `File` constructor does not take a URL. `openInputStream()` works with `file:` `Uri` values as well, so you might consider just going that route for both cases.

Comment: Wow what an answer, maybe a little over my head. I'll read over that link and see if i can figure it out.

Comment: Ok i'm accepting your answer but its not working for me, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21781831/android-upload-of-file-to-server