# Android Upload of File to Server

Tags: android

Based on the recommendations of a previous post I'm trying to use [Android: Uploading image on server with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789703/android-uploading-image-on-server-with-php) however I get a file not found exception.

Here's my function as described in the post above. My input for these are:

Gallery: uploadFile: `Source File not exist :content://media/external/images/media/342`
Photo: uploadFile: `Source File not exist: file:///storage/emulated/0/MyDir/blah`

These uri's are derived from the intent a lanched to catputre/select them. Any ideas why I get a `File Not Found` exception?

```
private void doFileUpload(String exsistingFileName){
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    DataInputStream inStream = null; 

    //String exsistingFileName = "/sdcard/six.3gp";
    // Is this the place are you doing something wrong.

    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary =  "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;
    String urlString = "http://192.168.1.5/upload.php";
    try
    {
        Log.e("MediaPlayer","Inside second Method");
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(exsistingFileName) );
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Allow Outputs
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        // Don't use a cached copy.
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        // Use a post method.
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
        dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + exsistingFileName +"\"" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        Log.e("MediaPlayer","Headers are written");
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        String LogString = "";

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)  {
            LogString= LogString + inputLine;
        }

        Log.i(Utils.TAG, LogString);
        // close streams
        fileInputStream.close();
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException ex)
    {
        Log.e("MediaPlayer", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
    catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        Log.e("MediaPlayer", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
    }

    //------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
    try {
        inStream = new DataInputStream ( conn.getInputStream() );
        String str;            
        while (( str = inStream.readLine()) != null)
        {
            Log.e("MediaPlayer","Server Response"+str);
        }
        /*while((str = inStream.readLine()) !=null ){

        }*/
        inStream.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ioex){
        Log.e("MediaPlayer", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i get a file not found exception

That is because neither of those are paths to files. You can tell that by looking at them. You also did not follow the instructions from [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21767941/115145).

Replace:

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(exsistingFileName) );
```

with:

```
InputStream contentInputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(exsistingFileName));
```

(and replace occurrences of `fileInputStream` with `contentInputStream` for the rest of your method)

Note that:

- This assumes that your `doFileUpload()` is implemented on some class that inherits from `Context`, such as an `Activity` or a `Service`. You will need to arrange to get a `ContentResolver` to `doFileUpload()` by other means if `doFileUpload()` does not have access to `getContentResolver()`.
- You could simplify matters a bit by passing in the `Uri` you received into `doFileUpload()`, rather than converting it to a `String` and then back into a `Uri`.
- You will need to invent your own filename for the `Content-Disposition:` header, as you do not get a filename from the `Uri`.

Comment: I also said your last answer maybe over my head.

Comment: @jcaruso: Unless you explain *specifically* what you do not understand, nobody is going to be able to offer clarification.

Comment: I wasn't just gonna have you explain it more without doing the reading first. I though i understood and did what you asked but obviously i was mistaken. I hate people that do not do their research and expect to be tough. However, back to your change above it seems to have worked (I have a file uploaded to my server at least) however it has no extension (jpg/png) though it does render when i go to the url

Comment: @jcaruso: A `Uri` is more or less a URL, and a URL does not necessarily have a file extension. Assuming that you are getting the `Uri` via `ACTION_PICK` or `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, see if the `Intent` you get in `onActivityResult()` has a MIME type that you can leverage. There's no guarantee that there will be one, but it's worth looking at.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get an InputStream from a Uri ? This might be easier :

```
private void doFileUpload(Uri fileUri){
    // some code
    InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileUri);
    // more code
    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + "some_file_name" +"\"" + lineEnd);
    // the rest of the code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In such scenarios, there can be different reasons. First, make sure that you have added READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in your AndroidManifest, and also you have added Runtime permissions for API level 19 and above. Then one of the reasons could be mentioned in the accepted answer. But those who are looking for a full detailed solution to upload all types of files to Server in Android can follow this article. [Upload File to Server in Android](https://handyopinion.com/upload-file-to-server-in-android-kotlin/). It describes all steps from picking file to the uploading.