# Android Studio get File from Gallery Intent

Tags: android, file, android-intent, gallery

Short answer is it possible to get original file from Gallery request,and if it possible how can i do it? This code doesn't work for me.

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
File file = new File(uri.getPath());
```

And the long Answer)):
I use this code to make gallery intent

```
addGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
             Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
             intent.setType("image/*");
             startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_IMAGE_REQUEST);
        }
    });
```

In mu onActivityResult i use this code

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {
        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case GALLERY_IMAGE_REQUEST:
                if (data != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Uri uri = data.getData();
                        File file = new File(uri.getPath());
                        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        inputStream.close();
                    } catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

And i cant get file.

The same code with getting bitmap from data works well but i need to get exactly file from gallery but not only Uri or Bitmap.

```
                 try
                    {
                        Uri uri = data.getData();
                        InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                        final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
                        imageStream.close();
                    } catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Comment: You should use picasso library its sooooooo much easier

Comment: Can i get file with Picasso? it is very important because in future i have to upload this file to server. I really dont need creating bitmap or setting image view i just need getting file from gallery.

Comment: Look at commonsware answer in this question some uri cant be used in file. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21781831/android-upload-of-file-to-server

Comment: JRowan thanks, i get that Gallery uri is not simple Uri, but my answer is still open. Is it possible to get right Uri from gallery data with the help of conotentResolver or may be other Utils?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to import a picture from gallery into your app (in a case your app own it), you need to copy it to your app data folder.

in your onActivityResult():

```
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO_FROM_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        try {
            // Creating file
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error occurred while creating the file");
            }

            InputStream inputStream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(photoFile);
            // Copying
            copyStream(inputStream, fileOutputStream);
            fileOutputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Creating the file method:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

Copy method:

```
public static void copyStream(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}
```

Comment: MohammadL thanks a lot i used your solution and it works much faster than my(i used to make Bitmap from data, compress and save to file ).

Comment: I get error at getActivity. How to fix?