# Android Large Image on Imageview Crashes App on OOM Error

Tags: java, android

The below code allows a user to pick 4 images from their gallery and upload to a server. At the moment It is uploading all 4 small images but when i try large images it crashes on OOM error.

Even when i try to load 2 large images the app crashes when i load a big images on OOM error. What is the most efficient way to handle such issues?. I have read this [Android Bitmaps](http://%20https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap#read-bitmap) but i don't seem to get how to implement in my four images code. I have tried Picasso but the app still behaves the same (ditto) above.

```
        SelectImageGallery1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSelect1);
        SelectImageGallery2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSelect2);
        SelectImageGallery3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSelect3);
        SelectImageGallery4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSelect4);

        UploadImageServer = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);

        SelectImageGallery1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image1 From Gallery"), 1);

            }
        });

        SelectImageGallery2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image4 From Gallery"), 2);
                }
          });

        SelectImageGallery3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image3 From Gallery"), 3);

            }
        });

        SelectImageGallery4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image4 From Gallery"), 4);

            }
        });

        UploadImageServer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                GetImageNameEditText1 = imageName1.getText().toString();
                GetImageNameEditText2 = imageName2.getText().toString();
                GetImageNameEditText3 = imageName3.getText().toString();
                GetImageNameEditText4 = imageName4.getText().toString();
               ImageUploadToServerFunction();
            }
        });

    }



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int RC, int RQC, Intent I) {
        super.onActivityResult(RC, RQC, I);
        if (RC == 1&&RQC == RESULT_OK&&I != null&&I.getData() != null) {
            Uri uri = I.getData();
            try {
                bitmap1 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                imageView1.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (RC == 2 && RQC == RESULT_OK && I != null && I.getData() != null) {
            Uri uri = I.getData();
            try {
                bitmap2 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                //bitmap1 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                imageView2.setImageBitmap(bitmap2);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (RC == 3 && RQC == RESULT_OK && I != null && I.getData() != null) {
            Uri uri = I.getData();
            byte[] imageAsBytes=null;
            try {
                bitmap3 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                //bitmap1 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                imageView3.setImageBitmap(bitmap3);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (RC == 4 && RQC == RESULT_OK && I != null && I.getData() != null) {
            Uri uri = I.getData();
            try {
                bitmap4 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                //bitmap1 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                imageView4.setImageBitmap(bitmap4);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public String getStringImage1(Bitmap bitmap1){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage1 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage1;
    }

    public String getStringImage2(Bitmap bitmap2){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage2 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage2;
    }
    public String getStringImage3(Bitmap bitmap3){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap3.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage3 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage3;
    }

    public String getStringImage4(Bitmap bitmap4){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap4.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage4 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage4;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was achieved by using Glide as follows. Using glide ensures the OOM errors are handled and they are not repeated on loading even a 30mb image.

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int RC, int RQC, Intent I) {
        super.onActivityResult(RC, RQC, I);
        if (RC == 1 && RQC == RESULT_OK && I != null && I.getData() != null) {
            Uri uri = I.getData();
            RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
                    .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);

            Glide.with(this)
                    .setDefaultRequestOptions(options)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .load(uri)
                    .centerInside()
                    .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>(512, 512) {
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap bitmap1, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                            imageView1.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
                            UploadActivity.this.bitmap1 = bitmap1;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {
                        }
                    });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

ByteArrayOutputStream holds all data in memory. So you cannot store data larger than the heap. Modify the "manifest" in the first way.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:largeHeap="true">
</application>
```

Use FileInputStream instead of ByteArrayOutputStream.

Comment: This has issues in the long run

Answer (score 0):

You should decode bitmap to decrease the size of bitmap before upload to sever:

You can change size(reqWidth\reqHeight) at your disposal
You can refer to my Github to get full code: [https://github.com/vancuong0429/ResizeImageUtil/blob/master/ResizeImageUtil](http://Refer)

To get a file from onActivityResult(), You can refer link

> [Android Studio get File from Gallery Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50456342/android-studio-get-file-from-gallery-intent)

In onActivityResult():

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (RC == 1 && RQC == RESULT_OK && I != null && I.getData() != null) {
        Uri uri = I.getData();
        // Creating file
        // Get the path from the Uri
        final String path = getPathFromURI(uri);
        if (path != null) {
            File yourFile = new File(path);
           bitmap1 = decodeBitmapFromFile(yourFile, 512, 512)
        }

    }
}

public String getPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
         String res = null;
         String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
         Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, 
        null, null);
         if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
             int column_index = 
          cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
          res = cursor.getString(column_index);
       }
       cursor.close();
       return res;
    }
 fun decodeBitmapFromFile(imageFile: File, reqWidth: Int, reqHeight: Int): Bitmap {
    val options = BitmapFactory.Options()
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.absolutePath, options)

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight)

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false
    var scaledBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.absolutePath, options)

    scaledBitmap = modifyOrientation(scaledBitmap, imageFile.absolutePath)
    return scaledBitmap
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Curong Nguyen. How is this implementable in my code?

Comment: getPathFromURI and decodeBitmapFromFile cannot be resolved!!

Comment: why? you added function getPathFromURI and decodeBitmapFromFile  to your code

Comment: No i didnt add i pasted your code as is and changed the imageview only

Comment: You must add the function to your code. I has to write the function